# Step by step filtering of an ActiveRecord using where function in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to realize free requests to a laser database. For example: give all shots with energy> 20J and duration <150fs and ...

My approach is to first find all shots with Energy> 20J and then to apply the duration < 150fs condition to these shots. And so on, until all search parameters have been processed.

```rb
ss.ssps.each do |ssp|
    selectedShots = 
      selectedShots.where("instancevalues.name = '#{ssp.instancevalue_name}'")
                   .where("instancevalues.data_numeric #{ssp.operator} #{ssp.value}")
end
```

This works as expected for one search parameter. The SQL statement looks like:

```
SELECT  `shots`.* FROM `shots` WHERE (instancevalues.name = 'Energy') 
                                 AND (instancevalues.data_numeric > 20.0)
```

With two search parameters, I would have expected Rails first to process the first parameter and create subset of shots like above. After this to apply the second parameter.

Instead, Rails generates one SQL statement of the form

```
SELECT  `shots`.* FROM `shots` WHERE 
           (instancevalues.name = 'Energy') 
       AND (instancevalues.data_numeric > 20.0) 
       AND (instancevalues.name = 'Duration') 
       AND (instancevalues.data_numeric < 150.0)
```

The result is of course empty. 
How I can implement a step by step filtering in rails?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to explain the essence of the problem, so I did not use the details of the model. But perhaps this simplification obstructs alternative solution.

I have models:

```rb
class Shot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :experement
  has_many :instancevaluesets
  has_many :instances, :through => :instancevaluesets
  has_many :instancevalues, :through => :instancevaluesets
```

```rb
class Instancevalueset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shot
  belongs_to :instance
  has_many :instancevalues
```

```rb
class Instancevalue < ActiveRecord::Base
 #  instancevalueset_id :integer(38)     not null
 #  name                :string(256)     not null
 #  data_numeric        :decimal(, )
  belongs_to :instancevalueset
```

After each Laser shot a new shot in db will be created.
The model Instancevalueset connects shot to a device (instance). A physical device creates an entry here for itself after a shot. Devices writes the results of a measurement in instancevalues with instancevaluesset_id als FK. My task is to find shots, which fulfil search parameters applied to intancevalues (measurement results).

My original code is:

```rb
  ss.ssps.each do |ssp|
          selectedShots = **selectedShots.joins(:instancevalues)**
            .where("instancevalues.name = '#{ssp.instancevalue_name}'")
            .where("instancevalues.data_numeric #{ssp.operator} #{ssp.value}")
      end
```

Assume a set of shots [a, b, c, d, e, f]. Shots [a, c, e]  have Energy > 20J, so after 1st ssp I want to get [a,c,e]. Now I want to filter short pulses from this set. Shot e is to long T = 200fs. So in 2nd iteration I want to apply ssp to [a,c,e] and to get [a,c].

The idea of @Mark is good, but it returns an array of queries applied to the db and not to previous set.

```rb
 selectedShots = ss.ssps.map do |ssp|
          selectedShots.joins(:instancevalues)
            .where("instancevalues.name = '#{ssp.instancevalue_name}'")
            .where("instancevalues.data_numeric #{ssp.operator} #{ssp.value}")
      end
```

If it would be possible to perform an AND merge of array, it would solve my problem. But if I test:

```rb
  selectedShots.last.merge(selectionShots.first)
```

I get again:

```
 ....WHERE (instancevalues.name = 'Energy') 
       AND (instancevalues.data_numeric > 20.0) 
       AND (instancevalues.name = 'Duration') 
       AND (instancevalues.data_numeric < 150.0)
```

Comment: Perhaps add more detail about your model(s)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When would these results of that union **not** be empty? Could you elaborate on this a little more with a description of your model and a clearer description of the end result you want?

Comment: Thanks to You comments. I have added some details more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Mark:

```rb
#2D array, one row contain ids of one query
      selectedShotsIDs = ss.ssps.map do |ssp|
          selectedShots.joins(:instancevalues)
            .where("instancevalues.name = '#{ssp.instancevalue_name}'")
            .where("instancevalues.data_numeric #{ssp.operator} #{ssp.value}").select(:id).map{|shot| shot.id}
      end

# Filter IDs that occur in all queries using array intersections
      filteredIDs = selectedShotsIDs.first
      selectedShotsIDs.each do |ss|
        filteredIDs = filteredIDs & ss
      end

      # get the shots
      selectedShots = Shot.where(id: filteredIDs )
```

May be it is inefficient, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
selectedShots = ss.ssps.map do |ssp|
  selectedShots.where("instancevalues.name = '#{ssp.instancevalue_name}'")
               .where("instancevalues.data_numeric #{ssp.operator} #{ssp.value}")
end
```

This will create an array with a separate entry for each ssp in the collection ssps, and will perform each query separately.

Comment: Thank You Mark. But second query is applied to the base amount in the database. Not on the result of the first query. If is exist a possibility to make a AND set of both results for equal shot ids it would solve my problem. I tried 
 selectedShots.first.merge(selectedShots.last)
but get again an empty set...